# Finding commas in strings using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, tagging

I'm trying to learn JS, so forgive me if you code makes the world explode.
Anyway, I am trying to make a tagging system interface similar to SOs. Where the user types in words and SO separates them on the comma (or on spacebar but I don't want that).

I am using jQuery to access the DOM (because it is so much easier), and I know there are various [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tag-it) that could do this and feed the homeless, but as I said I want to learn.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<input type="textbox" name="somebox" id"someid">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var startPos = 0;

    $("#someid").keyup(function() {
        var inputText = $(this).val();
        var commaPosition = inputText.indexOf(",", startPos);
        var foundWords = [];

        alert('Hello'); // even this doesn't work... why???
        if (commaSearch !== '-1') {

            // take the word:
            foundWords.push(inputText.slice(startPos,commaPosition));

            startPos = commaPosition + 1;
        }
    });
});
```

[It can also be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/9KVs4/). Nothing seems to work, not even the alert. Any help would be grateful.

Comment: If someone would like to cyber-punch me for wasting your time, you are more than welcome to do so.

Comment: No problem. Happens to us all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ampGY/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#someid").keyup(function() {
        var inputText = $(this).val();
        var foundWords = inputText.split(","); // or as posted elsewhere split(/\s*,\s*/g)
        if (foundWords.length>1) $("#tags").html(foundWords.join(";"))
    });
});
```

Comment: That's actually so much better than the monster I wrote.

Comment: I agree :) Feel free to vote up and/or accept - I do suggest you use Matt's regexp to trim the tags

Answer (score 2):

Problems:

- Invalid HTML - you're missing an `=` in between `id` and `"someid"`. This will make the `alert()` work.
- Use [`String.split(',')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) rather than `String.indexOf(',')`. To split and get rid of extra spaces: `inputText.split(/\s*,\s*/g)`
- I also get Uncaught ReferenceError: commaSearch is not defined. – Felix Kling

Demo with fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/2sE8b/

Comment: I also get `Uncaught ReferenceError: commaSearch is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to laugh, but you didn't have the `=` infront of the `id=someid` :D http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/9KVs4/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/9KVs4/3/) what you want?

As Matt Ball pointed out, you're missing the `=` sign after `id` in your HTML. Next, you use `commaPosition` then `commaSearch`. Next, you use the not-identity operator with a number and a string, which will always return `false`.